# Load SFML audio dlls

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, dll, sfml

I am trying to play sound files using C++, and I am using the audio library of SFML.

I read in the documentation that it needed the files openal32.dll and libsndfile-1.dll.

I moved those files into a folder with the path C:\Program Files\Platform Game\bin.  Now I was wondering how I would tell my program to look for those dll files in that location.  Currently I have to place the dll files in the same directory as my exe which I don't like to do.

Comment: "I have to place the dll files in the same directory as my exe which I don't like to do." Why not?

Comment: Because I would like to keep the exe file on my desktop while I keep the rest of the files my program uses in a seperate folder

Comment: And creating a shortcut to the exe file on the desktop would not suffice because...?

Comment: I actually just thought of doing that that is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

How windows looks up its dll files is a story in itself. You can find a start in the MSDN under the heading of [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx).